# Creating a regression model using Day of Week, Hour of Day, and Type of Media?

Tags: python, regression, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Working with Python 3 in a `Jupyter` notebook. I am trying to create a regression model (equation?) to predict the `Eng as % of Followers` variable. I'd be given `Media Type`, `Hour Created`, and `Day of Week`. These should all be treated as categorical variables.

Here is some of the past data I have.

```
    Media Type  Eng as % of Followers   Hour Created    Day of Week
0   Video   0.0136  23  Tuesday
1   Video   0.0163  22  Wednesday
2   Video   0.0163  22  Tuesday
3   Video   0.0196  22  Friday
4   Video   0.0179  20  Thursday
5   Photo   0.0087  14  Wednesday
```

I've created `dummy variables` using `pd.get_dummies`, but I'm not sure I did that correctly - the problem specifically lies with the `Hour Created` variable. They're numbers, but I want them treated as categories. For example, Hour 22 might be a performance booster, but that shouldn't imply anything about Hours 21 or 23.

I'm also curious if I could have my model factor in the interaction between `Day of Week` and `Hour Created` (maybe Hour 22 is a boost on most days, but 22-Friday causes a dip) like I've seen done with patsy... but that might be me getting greedy.

Here is how I created my dummy variables, which sets me up for the issue of having `Hour Created` as a quantitative variable, instead of qualitative. Also, the Vars dataframe that I'd use going forward now doesn't have the very thing that I'm trying to predict. Could that possibly be right?

```
Vars = Training[['Hour Created','Day of Week','Media Type']]
Result = Training['Eng as % of Followers']
Vars = pd.get_dummies(data=Vars, drop_first=True)
```

If someone could help with the Hour Created problem, that would be a great start.... And then, not sure where to go from there. I've seen people use the ols function in this situation. Or linear_model from sklearn. I'm struggling with how to interpret the results from either, and especially struggling with how I'd plug a dataframe of those 3 independent variables into that model. If someone can make a suggestion, I'll try to run with it.

Edit:
Including a couple of ways I tried to create this model. Here's the first, which I assume is using my Hour data incorrectly. And being that the dataframe I'm passing into it doesn't even have Eng as % of Followers as a column header, I'm not even sure what it's trying to predict...

```
Vars_train, Vars_test, Result_train, Result_test = train_test_split(Vars, Result, test_size = .20, random_state = 40)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression() 
regr.fit(Vars_train, Result_train)
predicted = regr.predict(Vars_test)
```

When I try to use the ols method as follows, I get an invalid syntax error. I've tried different variations to no avail.

```
fit1 = ols('Eng as % of Followers ~ C(Day of Week) + C(Hour Created) + C(Media Type)', data=Training).fit()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Also please paste the full error message you are getting.

Comment: Python 3. Edited.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message in full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. One way to make sure that you are doing dummy coding correctly is to convert the columns to `str` types. In your case you want consider `Hour Created` as categorical though it is numeric in nature, so it is better to convert them to strings before doing dummy coding.
2. In order to capture interaction between `Day of Week` and `Hour Created` do a feature engineering and create your own feature by multiplying `Day of Week` and `Hour Created` and feed it as an input to your model.
3. In order to understand/interpret your model you can look at the weights/coefficients of different features which gives an idea of how each and every feature impacts your target variable positively or negatively.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df 

Media   Type    Eng_as_%_of_Followers   Hour_Created    Day_of_Week
0   0   Video   0.0136                  23              Tuesday
1   1   Video   0.0163                  22              Wednesday
2   2   Video   0.0163                  22              Tuesday
3   3   Video   0.0196                  22              Friday
4   4   Video   0.0179                  20              Thursday
5   5   Photo   0.0087                  14              Wednesday 

df["Hour_Created"] = df["Hour_Created"].astype(str)
df["Interaction"] = df["Hour_Created"] + "_" +df["Day_of_Week"] 

X = df.drop("Eng_as_%_of_Followers", axis=1)
Y = df["Eng_as_%_of_Followers"]

X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_encoded, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

coef_dict = dict(zip(X_encoded.columns, reg.coef_))

coef_dict

{'Day_of_Week_Friday': 0.0012837455830388678,
 'Day_of_Week_Thursday': 0.0007424028268551229,
 'Day_of_Week_Tuesday': -0.0008084805653710235,
 'Day_of_Week_Wednesday': -0.0012176678445229678,
 'Hour_Created_14': -0.0012176678445229678,
 'Hour_Created_20': 0.0007424028268551229,
 'Hour_Created_22': 0.0004752650176678456,
 'Hour_Created_23': 0.0,
 'Interaction_14_Wednesday': -0.0012176678445229678,
 'Interaction_20_Thursday': 0.0007424028268551229,
 'Interaction_22_Friday': 0.0012837455830388678,
 'Interaction_22_Tuesday': -0.0008084805653710235,
 'Interaction_22_Wednesday': 0.0,
 'Interaction_23_Tuesday': 0.0,
 'Media': -0.0008844522968197866,
 'Type_Photo': -0.0012176678445229708,
 'Type_Video': 0.0012176678445229685}
```

Of course the results may not be really interesting here, coz I was just working with 6 data points.

Answering your questions

1. You can find out the `y_intercept` using `reg.intercept_`
2. Yes you can plug in new values for x and get your target variable by using `reg.predict(x)`, where x is your new input.
3. Regression done by `OLS` and `sklearn` are one and the [same](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html). OLS is nothing but a way to solve the optimization problem which we have in regression.

Comment: Appreciate this a ton! I'm lost on a couple things, though. (1) Where can I find the y-intercept of my regression formula? (2) Would I then be able to plug values into this regression model in order to predict new % of Engagement values? (3) How different, if at all, is this from the OLS method - and do you know why my execution (in my question details) is not executing? The error reads:

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    C(Hour Created)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you think the above answer answers your questions, I request you to accept it as a verified answer so that it might helps others who might visit this question down the lane.